# Read big json file with php

Tags: php, python

I've read somewhere that I should use the library `salsify/jsonstreamingparser` to open a big json file but it's giving me the same error as with `json_decode`:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /data/www/default/database/vendor/salsify/json-streaming-parser/src/Listener/InMemoryListener.php on line 92
```

I have to do it in php because I'm using a free hosting which doesn't have python.

Basically what I want to do is download a big json file unzip it and process the content. I don't know why in php I wasn't able to do it in all day but in python I did it in 5 minutes:

```
import os
import json
import urllib
import zipfile

json_file = 'AllSets-x.json'
zip_file = json_file + '.zip'
urllib.urlretrieve ("https://mtgjson.com/json/" + zip_file, zip_file)

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(dir_path + "/" + zip_file, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall(dir_path)
zip_ref.close()

json_data = json.load(open(json_file, 'r'))
print json_data.keys()[0]
```

This is what I have in php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
include "../credentials.php";

error_reporting(E_ALL); # Reports all errors
ini_set('display_errors','Off'); # Do not display errors for the end-users (security issue)
ini_set('error_log','/tmp/php-errors.log'); # Set a logging file

// Override the default error handler behavior
set_exception_handler(function($exception) {
   $logger->error($exception);
   echo "Something went wrong!";
});

$logger = new Monolog\Logger('channel-name');
$logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('/tmp/php-errors.log', Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));

$logger->info("Parsing json file");
$listener = new \JsonStreamingParser\Listener\InMemoryListener();

$json_file = __DIR__ . "/AllSets-x.json";
$stream = fopen($json_file, 'r');
try {
    $parser = new \JsonStreamingParser\Parser($stream, $listener);
    $parser->parse();
    fclose($json_file);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    fclose($json_file);
    throw $e;
}

$logger->info("Json file parsed");
$json_data = $listener->getJson();
$logger->info("Displaying json data");
var_dump($json_data);
```

Comment: Which Listener would be the correct one?

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll see if I can finally make it work.

Comment: Python's `json.load()` appears to be a streaming implementation which is likely why it doesn't run afoul of your memory constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the InMemoryListener certainly defeats the purpose of a streaming parser. That'll just unpack everything into memory (likely worse memory-wise than plain [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode)).

You'll need to catch each JSON object block individually, if you want to work under such constraints.

There's the [SimpleObjectQueueListener](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser/blob/master/src/Listener/SimpleObjectQueueListener.php) which could possibly fit the bill. If the specific JSON has a bunch of `[{…}, {…}, {…}]` objects to be processed:

```
$listener = new \JsonStreamingParser\Listener\SimpleObjectQueueListener("print_r", 0);
// would just print out each object block from the JSON stream
```

Obviously you would use a callback like "`process_my_json_blobs`" instead. (Or a prepared callback like `[$pdo, "execute"]` perhaps.)

---

Btw, reading the whole JSON input just works on your local Python, because there's usually no `memory_limit` as for common PHP setups. (Python at best relies on the systems `ulimit`.)